# Need to create a query that will show orders for April Roberts. I just need output to show OrderID and OrderDate. Here is what I have so far

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
ORDER_ITEM.OrderID, 
ORDERS.OrderDate
FROM ORDER_ITEM LEFT JOIN ORDERS 
ON ORDER_ITEM.OrderID = ORDERS.OrderID 
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE 
ON ORDERS.CustomerID = PEOPLE.PeopleId AND ORDERS.EmployeeID = PEOPLE.PeopleId
where PEOPLE.FirstName + PEOPLE.LastName = 'April Roberts'
```

My results are outputting 0 rows.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If you are using INNER JOIN, then if there are no results to join in the joined tables (PEOPLE for example) then there won't be any result at all. Try using LEFT JOIN instead?

Comment: Daniel, Thank you so much, that worked! :)

Comment: No prob :) Good luck!

Comment: How can I make it only display April Roberts orders?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have data in the table that match your criteria. e.g. You have orders by the person with the name April Roberts. If you use LEFT JOIN, the query will return all results despite if you do not have any order by the person. So, INNER JOIN or simply JOIN is fine if you ONLY want orders that associates with the person.

```
SELECT oi.OrderID, o.OrderDate 
FROM ORDER_ITEM oi 
JOIN ORDERS o ON oi.OrderID = o.OrderID 
JOIN PEOPLE p ON o.CustomerID = p.PeopleId
WHERE p.FirstName = 'April' AND p.LastName = 'Roberts'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work better for the search (you are using a space that doesn't exist)

```
SELECT OI.OrderID, O.OrderDate 
FROM ORDER_ITEM OI
LEFT JOIN ORDERS O ON OI.OrderID = O.OrderID 
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P ON O.CustomerID = P.PeopleId AND O.EmployeeID = P.PeopleId 
WHERE P.FirstName='April' AND P.LastName = 'Roberts';
```

However, logically, CustomerID and EmployeeID can't match the same employee. You'd need a second link to people

```
SELECT OI.OrderID, O.OrderDate 
FROM ORDER_ITEM OI
LEFT JOIN ORDERS O ON OI.OrderID = O.OrderID 
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE P ON O.CustomerID = P.PeopleId
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE E ON O.EmployeeID = E.PeopleId 
WHERE P.FirstName='April' AND P.LastName = 'Roberts';
```

Comment: Thank you Jacques...When you do this all day, the simplest queries are the harder ones, HA.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you want the people record match employee and customer of the same order, but the customer will never equal the employee of course.

Is April Roberts the customer or the employee? Decide and then select the data from the orders table for that customer or employee:

```
select orderid, orderdate
from orders
where customerid in 
(
  select peopleid 
  from people 
  where firstname = 'April'
  and lastname = 'Roberts'
);
```

No need to join the order_item table. No need to join at all. Only join when you want joined data.

I am using `IN` for the case there exist two April Roberts. If there is a constraint on the table preventing that, then you can change `IN` to `=`.

If you were really interested in the orders linked to some April Roberts, not knowing whether she is employee or customer, you'd use `EXISTS` instead:

```
select orderid, orderdate
from orders o
where exists
(
  select *
  from people p
  where p.firstname = 'April'
  and p.lastname = 'Roberts'
  and p.peopleid in (o.customerid, o.employeeid)
);
```

There is another error in your query by the way:

```
where PEOPLE.FirstName + PEOPLE.LastName = 'April Roberts'
```

You are adding two values here (`+` is for numeric addition), so MySQL converts the strings `FirstName` and `LastName` to numbers. Such conversion from a string that starts with a letter results in the value zero in MySQL, so you have `where 0 + 0 = 0` which is always true. If `+` would do string concatenation as you obviously supposed (which is the `||` operator in standard SQL and the `CONCAT` function in MySQL), then you'd probably have gotten `where 'AprilRoberts' = 'April Roberts'` which would always be false.